# Show Powerpoint Presentation in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5, ios4

In my app I have dropbox implementation and user can download the documents from dropbox and see that one by one like a slideshow. My Problem is that if user downloads .ppt file then how to show powerpoint presentation with all its animations on iPhone without using other app like slide shark.

Comment: so do you want to write your own ppt reader?

Comment: yes as like slide shark does. Can you give me some proceeding idea?

Answer (score 3):

Only way is Using the [Quick Look Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html).

Use the [Quick Look framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html) to provide previews of items that are in formats you don’t handle—such as iWork or **Microsoft Office**. This framework affords you more control over the preview process than you get from the `UIDocumentInteractionController` class—including choosing whether the preview is displayed in the context of a navigation controller or modally (full screen). The primary class in this framework is QLPreviewController, which provides a specialized view for previewing an item. It relies on a `delegate for` mediating preview actions, and a data source for providing the preview items.

In `iOS 4.2` and later, the specialized view presented by a Quick Look preview controller includes an action button with a Print item. If the controller can provide a preview of a file, it can also print it. There is no printing code for you to write.

**To display a Quick Look preview controller you can use any of these options:**

1. Push it into view using a `UINavigationController` object.
2. Present it modally, full screen, using the
   `presentModalViewController:animated:` method of its parent class,
   `UIViewController`.
3. Present a document interaction controller (as described in
   “Previewing and Opening Files.” The user can then invoke a Quick
   Look preview controller by choosing Quick Look from the document
   interaction controller’s options menu.

A Quick Look preview controller can display previews for the following items:

> **Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)**
>
> iWork documents
>
> Rich Text Format (RTF) documents
>
> PDF files
>
> Images
>
> Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the
>   public.text type (see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference)
>
> Comma-separated value (csv) files

Comment: I had previously implemented Quick Look framework to show ppt files but it shows the slides in a web view and slides are placed vertically  one by one. I don't want that I want ppt files to show as they are with same type of animations just as in slide shark app.

Answer (score 0):

look at `UIDocumentationInteractionController`, which may be easier than using Quick Look, depending on your needs, you can control animation better then Quick look but need lots of digging.